# Best practice for handling appsettings values

Tags: c#, .net, tdd

I'm trying to write code as better I can, for that reason looking at some code I wrote in past I've seen that I access to .config appsetting with something as

```
 Public void Do()
{
 Var x = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("foo");
 doSomethingElse(x);
}
```

Writing test on this method I asked myself wasn't it better to have an interface with properties that exposes all the .config AppSettings values ? This would allow me to replace via IoC the real implementation.

on the other side I ask is it correct to wrap all those values in a class/interface?what if I've different assemblies that compose an application and I need to access to that object? Supposed that it will be in a shared project does it make sense to have a value as

```
 Int ModelAvalue {get{};}
```

Defined in that class that would never be used in ModelB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configuration is a dependency.  I think your idea about creating an interface that returns the most appropriate type helps both with testing and makes your code easier to understand.  It also gives you the flexibility to change where your configuration is stored in the future.

To answer your other question, it would be better to have interfaces smaller and more specific, as per the [interface segregation principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).  You could have different interfaces in which each interface is a group of closely related settings.  For example, you would not have an interface that has your database connection string and your log file path.

```
public interface IDatabaseConfiguration
{
    string ConnectionString { get; }
}

public interface IBlogConfiguration
{
    int NumberOfPostsPerPage { get; }
}

public class AppConfiguration : IDatabaseConfiguration, IBlogConfiguration
{
    public string ConnectionString 
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDb"].ConnectionString; }
    }

    public int NumberOfPostsPerPage 
    {
        get { return int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PostsPerPage"]); }
    }
}
```

In the future, if you decide that `NumberOfPostsPerPage` should be stored elsewhere, you can create a different concrete implementation of `IBlogConfiguration`

Comment: thanks for your response,I agree with you at 100%, so in a case I need to have server address,host and tcp buffer size I put them in a interface , for logging I put it somewhere else. What If I've common values, for example a MaxRetryCount ? Do I have to define those common in a interface and make other interface to inherit from it?

Comment: It depends on the context of `MaxRetryCount`, you could have a separate interface altogether for global configuration, but `MaxRetryCount` may mean different things if it's referring to a database vs a web service.

Comment: Excuse me it was related to a server reconnection value (in the case a TCP server connection drops), btw I've understood your mind... I'll adopt